# Swagger: как прикрутить собственный json с api-docs?

Tags: java, swagger

В сваггере, при желании, можно скачать json с api-docs, в котором будет вся та же сгенерированная сваггером информация, которая отображена в графическом интерфейсе. Я хочу отделить документацию от кода в этом смысле и использовать этот json, поправить его и дополнить.

Сейчас документация генерируется при помощи такого бина:

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(SWAGGER_BASE_PACKAGE))
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(Api.class))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}
```

Хочется, чтобы она генерировалась через этот самый json:

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "description": "Api Documentation",
    "version": "1.0",
    "title": "Api Documentation",
    "termsOfService": "urn:tos",
    "contact": {
      
    },
    "license": {
      "name": "Apache 2.0",
      "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"
    }
  },
...
```

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: `/v2/api-docs` или что?

Comment: да, этот самый.

Comment: Из вопроса не понятно что вы хотите сделать, заменить конфиг спрингфокса на raw json?

Comment: Да, чтобы страница сваггера генерировалась не из классов, а из json. И выглядела так же, как и страница, которая генерится на примере. То есть, я хочу подменить ресурс, используемый для генерации, json-файлом.

Comment: Создайте файл в ресурсах и отдавайте его как ресурс, а в настройках спрингфокса измените url json'a, а вот как изменить можно попробовать тут поискать https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2126